# Rigidbody GameObject is restricted in movement while moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm pretty new to Unity, but I managed to put together a script that moves the player around a plane. Problem is, after moving a certain distance, it won't move any further. I want the movement to be unrestricted.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement_Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float default_speed;
    public float sprint_multiplier;

    private float speed;

    private void Update()
    {
        speed = default_speed;
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontal, 0.0f, vertical);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            speed = speed * sprint_multiplier;
        else
            speed = default_speed;
        rb.MovePosition(movement * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: it  teleports the object to the new position (rather than performing a smooth transition).

Comment: you are using moveposition, and moving to at best say 1,1 or -1,-1 you meant to set velocity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your MovePosition outside of Update to FixedUpdated.
FixedUpdate is the right place to put physic code.

You need too to reset your movement vector on each update if you like to get the new displacement vector to skip a drag movement and need to add timefactor * Time.fixedDeltaTime

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement_Player : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody rb;
public float default_speed;
public float sprint_multiplier;

private float speed;

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero
    speed = default_speed;
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontal, 0.0f, vertical);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        speed = speed * sprint_multiplier;
    else
        speed = default_speed;

}
void FixedUpdate()

{

    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

}
```

}